How to remove stress periods from a simulation?
I need to dynamically change the amount of stress periods in a MODFLOW 6 model. I am using flopy to prepare and process the mf6 model files in Python. After loading the model via
sim = flopy.mf6.modflow.MFSimulation.load(...) and gwf = sim.get_model(model_name)

it is no problem to INCREASE the number of stress periods, but I can not remove any of the existing ones
When accessing the tdis package of sim object, I can set the number of stress periods nper. When my target nper is larger than the initial nper, I can further add stress periods to e.g. the recharge package without a problem. However, when I decrease the number of stress periods and subsequently define a dictionary of stress periods with the appropriate number of stress periods, my terminal is flooded with
WARNING: Stress period value 20 in package rch is greater than the number of stress periods defined in nper.

Of course, I use
gwf.rch.stress_period_data.set_data(recharge_stress_period_dictionary) 
gwf.rch.write()

to write my changes to modflow files.
I dug around and I found a method of the mfdatalist module, remove_transient_key(transient_key), however it is not intended for the end user. So, therefore I wonder, whether there is a reliable method of removing stress periods from transient mf6 packages.
